# Can we read environment variable on Azure Kubernetes Pod?

Tags: c#, kubernetes, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-aks

We have deployed some of the services (like Web API) on Azure Kubernetes. When we logged onto the Azure Kubernetes Pods and execute the printenv on the terminal, it shows environment variable on the screen including the service we deployed like

```
<SERVICENAME>_PORT=
<SERVICENAME>_HOST=`
.....
```

How can we read above variable value in the .Net code? I tried with the below code but it didn't work

```
 var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings_prod.json", true, true).AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();

var port =  Configuration["<SERVICENAME>_PORT"]
```

Comment: Maybe this helps you https://anthonychu.ca/post/aspnet-core-appsettings-secrets-kubernetes/

Comment: Hi, did any of the answer solve your issue? Please mark the correct answer as solved or leave a comment if you are still facing some issues thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works.

Answer (score 2):

To access env from k8s pods, you need to provide those env through pod's `spec.containers[].env[]`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: demo-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mycontainer
    image: demo/new-image
    env:
      # define env from k8s secret (used specially for credentials)
      - name: SECRET_USERNAME
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: mysecret
            key: username
      # define env from configmap
      - name: SPECIAL_CREDENTIALS
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef: 
              name: configmap-name
              key: config.json
      # define value directly 
      - name: DEMO_GREETING
        value: "Hello from the environment"
```

Comment: These are the variables, which are created by us but I want to read the environment, which created the AKS.

Comment: These are the variables, which are created by us but I want to read the environment, which created the AKS. 

More description about my query:
We have deployed some services (Web API) on the AKS and AKS automatically creates some environment on it's own (not added my us), which has name like 

```
<SERVICENAME>_PORT=
<SERVICENAME>_HOST=`
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the environment variable to code you can use the value of `config map` of kubernetes. it will set the value in environment os of pod and in code you can get it from there.

for secure data you can use the `secret`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [downward-api](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/#the-downward-api) to expose pod information to containers.